Do "kook" and "kooky" have a negative connotation in American English?
I am aware that in the context of surfing, these words are derogatory but in this thread I'd like to focus on their connotation in broader everyday contexts.
Based on the definition provided by Cambridge dictionary, it must have a positive connotation:

kooky
adjective mainly US informal
uk  /ˈkuː.ki/ us  /ˈkuː.ki/
(especially of a person) strange in his or her appearance or behaviour, especially in a way that is interesting:
She's got this kooky, high-pitched voice.

And I have also heard it used in contexts in movies where someone was talking about the quirky friend. It came off as a loving way to convey that they found their  friend quirky in a lovable way rather than in an insulting/strange/off-putting way.
However, given other definitions in other dictionaries (crazy, a strange person, etc.), I'd say these words can take on a negative connotation in some contexts.
Are my assumptions incorrect? If so, please correct me.

Sometimes negative, sometimes not. There's no answer like "it's always negative" or "it's never negative". How would you feel being called strange? It would probably depend who by and in what context. Try and think about how people use terms like strange, unusual, different, unique, weird, crazy, interesting, etc, in real-life interactions. (The Cambridge definition certainly doesn't suggest it must be positive, only that it can be positive in so far as "interesting" is positive, which again - context.)

I think that the connotation of these can be flavored by  one meaning of the noun they derive from, cuckoo (n.) "a silly or slightly crackbrained person" and (adj.) "deficient in sense or intelligence : silly" However, to call someone cuckoo  is a big step beyond kooky. There is a quite a range between silly and deficient in intelligence--only the former might sometimes be endearing.

According to Green’s Dictionary of Slang the term mainly conveys an idea of excessive eccentricity: Kooky- odd, eccentric (often with overtones of charm). https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/3ampwzi

I would argue that "kook" is almost always negative, but "kooky" can range from less negative to downright positive.

@DougWarren A quick search in Google Books shows instances of lovable / adorable / delightful / charming kook" None strikes me as unusual.

Depending on how it's pronounced, kooky could sound like spooky or cookie.

@WeatherVane Where do they pronounce it like cookie?

@Barmar in David Bowie's song Kooks, although he sings 'kooks' with the long vowel, he sings 'kooky' with the short vowel.

@WeatherVane Is it necessary for a rhyme scheme? Songs and poetry often bend normal rules.

@Barmar please see lyrics. There are other 'poetic' rhymes such as 'story / sorry' but kooky is even weaker, with 'pick on you / kooky too'.

@WeatherVane When I try to play it, it stops at "pick on you". Apparently I need an Apple Music subscription to hear more. But he rhymes "shoes" and "rules". In any case, I suspect this may be an ideosyncratic affectation, not a common pronunciation (or maybe it's more common on that side of the pond than I realize).

The full OED defines kooky as Cranky, crazy, eccentric. Unless the speaker is some kind of fetishist, I think you can safely assume he's not being complimentary if he says You're kooky!

@Barmar sorry about that: I have the album, but I would rhyme kooky with cuckoo.

We love our kooks. Don't mess with them. [joke]

It's like "silly goose," fine if you're three, but nobody wants to be "kooky" forever; that becomes bizarre, tiring.

Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) gives first published occurrence dates of 1959 for kooky and 1960 for kook. Aside from those dates, however, that dictionary's entries for the two words are identical to the ones that appear in the Eighth Collegiate (1973, the earliest edition in the Collegiate series to include either word):

kook n {by shortening and alter. fr. cuckoo} one whose ideas or actions are eccentric, fantastic, or insane : SCREWBALL [defined elsewhere in the same dictionary as "a whimsical, eccentric, or crazy person"]
...
*kooky also kookie adj having the characteristics of a kook: CRAZY, OFFBEAT

A somewhat more detailed view of kook and kooky as evolving terms is evident in various editions of American Slang Dictionary. From Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, American Slang Dictionary (1960):

kook n. An odd, eccentric, disliked person; a "drip" [defined elsewhere in the same dictionary as "Any person, usu. a male teenager or student, who is disliked or who is objectionable, usu. because he is  a bore, introverted, overly solicitous, or is not hip to the fads, fashions, and typical behavior patterns of his age group"]; a nut. Teeenage use since 1958; rapidly becoming a pop. fad word kooky adj. Crazy, nuts; odd, eccentric; having the attributes of a "drip."

The supplemented edition of Wentworth & Flexner, American Slang Dictionary (1967) adds this new definition to the entry reproduced from 1960:

kook n. A beginning or inexperienced surfer. Some surfer use.

And from Robert Chapman, New Dictionary of American Slang (1986):

kook 1 n fr 1950s teenagers An eccentric person; = NUT, SCREWBALL.: The bomb cannot be exploded by a single "kook"—Nation/ The early Streisand played kook—Look 2 modifier: did a kook piece with dancers—Village Voice 3 n surfers A novice surfer {fr cuckoo}
kookie or kooky adj fr 1050s teenagers Crazy; eccentric; = DIPPY [defined elsewhere in the same dictionary as "Crazy; foolish; whimsically silly", GOOFY [defined elsewhere in the same dictionary as "Silly; foolish; crazy; dotty," with the further note "Nearly always has an affectionate and amused connotation"]: make you seem a little kookie—David Halberstam/ the kooky stunt so pleased him—Time

A major cultural reference point for the word kooky in the early 1960s was the character "Kookie Kookson in the TV series 77 Sunset Strip, which ran on ABC from 1958 to 1964. Here is Wikipedia's note on this character in its entry for the show:

The show's breakout character, who had not been included in the pilot film, was Gerald Lloyd "Kookie" Kookson III (Edd Byrnes), the rock and roll-loving, wisecracking, hair-combing hipster and aspiring PI who initially works as the valet parking attendant at Dino's, the club next to the detectives' office. Kookie often becomes involved in the firm's cases and is eventually made a full partner in the firm, with his own office.
...
The Kookie character became a cultural phenomenon, with his slang expressions such as "ginchy" (cool) and "piling up Zs" (sleeping). When Kookie helped the detectives on a case by singing a song, Edd Byrnes began a singing career with the novelty single "Kookie, Kookie (Lend Me Your Comb)," based on his frequent combing of his hair; this featured Connie Stevens on vocals in the chorus and the song, with words and music by Irving Taylor, became the first hit single for the recently established Warner Bros. Records. Kookie was also used to provide product placement for Harley-Davidson, appearing on their Topper motor scooter in the show and in Harley-Davidson advertisements.

A footnote in Charles McDowell, Campaign Fever: The National Folk Festival, from New Hampshire to November, 1964 offers this contemporaneous definition of kook as used in in a political contexts:

A "kook" is an eccentric, a crank, a nut. In California in 1964 the term implied far-right Republicanism, an excess of zeal, a tendency to impulsive behavior, and proud refusal to concede that political practicality had any place in the American way of life. The term was relative and opinions differed as to its proper application: appearance may have had something to do with it . A little old lady in tennis shoes (Attorney General Stanley Mosk's phrase) was generally regarded as a kook in the political arena. Ronald Reagan was not. The term was used freely by the Goldwater staff to describe embarrassing Goldwater fans. I once heard Richard Kleindienst say, when asked if a fiery-eyed woman he had been talking to was a kook: "Is she a kook? She is a kook's kook—a kook other kooks can look up to."

William Safire, Safire's Political Dictionary (1972/2008) extends the political use of the term beyond 1964:

kooks, nuts and Extremists; far-right or far-left wingers; distinguished by hate campaigns, occasional scruffiness, and unconventional political behavior.
...
Politically, nuts and kooks came into popularity as a derogation of the more extreme supporters of Senator Barry Goldwater before his nomination in 1964. Goldwater himself used the word, according to publisher John S. Knight in a post-convention interview: "He {Goldwater} remarked with a wry smile that some of the 'kooks' supporting him are convinced that the concept of metropolitan government is the handiwork of the Communist Party."
...
In the late '60s the word kooks (along with beats and potheads) was applied less to right-wingers and more to members of the New Left, especially those who burned draft cards and participated in antiwar demonstrations.

Of course, in situations where the mainstream of a political party embraces views formerly associated with its "lunatic fringe," characterizing those who hold such views as kooks loses much of its sting (not to say intelligibility). This may help explain why kooks doesn't seem to be especially common in U.S. political slang today.

Conclusions
In the progress of the definitions in Dictionary of American Slang across multiple editions, we can trace the evolution of kook and kooky as terms of dislike and even contempt to expressions that at least sometimes indicates indulgence and even affection. Notably, drip never escaped its original utterly derogatory sense.
Today, U.S. English speakers sometimes use terms such as "lovable kook" in essentially the same sense that they might use with "lovable eccentric," "lovable nut," or "lovable weirdo," and they sometimes use kooky in the sense of "goofily unrealistic but harmless." Nevertheless, the core meanings of kook and kooky are not positive overall, and some people continue to use them in situations where they do not intend to convey any hint of lovableness in the person or idea so described.
